# Mouse movement problem on a webpage ( JavaScript )

Tags: javascript, html, scroll

I have 2 set of code
The following works on firefox

```
x=e.clientX + document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
y=e.clientY +document.documentElement.scrollTop -67;
```

and this works on Chrome

```
x=e.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft ;
y=e.clientY + document.body.scrollTop - 67 ;
```

i tried to combine the code , but it doesn't work properly in Firefox then.

```
    if( document.documentElement){
x=e.clientX + document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
y=e.clientY +document.documentElement.scrollTop -67;
}
if( document.body){
x=e.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft ;
y=e.clientY + document.body.scrollTop - 67 ;
}
```

Why is this happening ?

My html is some thing like this , Does this have some thing to do with it?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Position stuff is a royal pain. It looks like you have to use *both* of them. There's very similar code in the jQuery source which may help:

```
if ( event.pageX == null && event.clientX != null ) {
    var doc = document.documentElement,
        body = document.body;

    event.pageX = event.clientX + (doc && doc.scrollLeft || body && body.scrollLeft || 0) - (doc && doc.clientLeft || body && body.clientLeft || 0);
    event.pageY = event.clientY + (doc && doc.scrollTop  || body && body.scrollTop  || 0) - (doc && doc.clientTop  || body && body.clientTop  || 0);
}
```

I don't know why they're doing that (on first glance, that code looks unnecessarily complicated) but I'm guessing there's a good reason, so you might try doing the same thing. That, adapted to your situation, might look like this:

```
var doc = document.documentElement,
    body = document.body;
x = e.clientX + (doc && doc.scrollLeft || body && body.scrollLeft || 0) - (doc && doc.clientLeft || body && body.clientLeft || 0);
y = e.clientY + (doc && doc.scrollTop  || body && body.scrollTop  || 0) - (doc && doc.clientTop  || body && body.clientTop  || 0) - 67;
```

---

**Somewhat off-topic**: For positioning stuff, I'd really use a library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com), [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/), [Closure](http://code.google.com/closure/library), [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org), or [any of several others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries). Then you get the benefit of lots of eyes on the code, lots of people using the code and reporting edge cases, etc., etc.

Comment: It worked ! :)      

Just one thing i wanted to ask you.    Why didnt it work in my case , The code i wrote ?      and i didnt understand whats the significanse of $$ and the || and also what has the subtraction sign used ?  ( - )

Comment: @Adi: I don't know why yours didn't work, I try to leave the vagaries of position stuff to people who maintain libraries. `&&` is the JavaScript **AND** operator, and `||` is the JavaScript **OR** operator. They're a bit more interesting (and more poweful) than the straight logical operators in most programming languages, more here: http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/javascripts-curiously-powerful-or.html

Comment: @Adi: your code doesn't work because your `if` conditions are always true.

Comment: @Adi, @Pumbaa80: **Doh** -- yeah, in particular the `if (document.body)` condition that's *after* the `if (document.documentElement)` condition will always be true, making the `documentElement` part dead code.

Answer (score 0):

It's due to an [old WebKit issue](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=2891) (which is closed as WontFix for some reason).

You can do something like what *T.J. Crowder* said, but it's somewhat costy. Your best bet is
**feature testing** scroll values (but only after the document is ready!).

```
var SCROLL_ROOT = (function() {
  var html = document.documentElement,
      scrollTop = html.scrollTop,
      root;
  html.scrollTop++;
  root = (html.scrollTop != scrollTop + 1) ? document.body : html;
  html.scrollTop--;
  return root;
})();
```

And your code becomes

```
x = e.clientX + SCROLL_ROOT.scrollLeft;
y = e.clientY + SCROLL_ROOT.scrollTop - 67;
```

Comment: @galambalazs   -    This code doesnt seem to work in Firefox, althought its working great in Chrome

Comment: *"...it's somewhat costly..."* In real-world terms, I suspect not. :-) You'd need to be doing this hundreds of thousands -- if not millions -- of times in a loop to see an perceptible difference, and I suspect any such loop would be dominated by other aspects. And apparently there's a reason they do it everytime (though as I said, I find it odd too).

Comment: @Adi Mathur - Make sure to run the test after document is ready. It works for me in FF4.0b11

Comment: @T.J. Crowder - What if it's a `mousemove` event handler? Even if he's using some kind of throttle/debounce, **efficiency** is not to be ignored. It's also far more **readable**, *reusable*.

Comment: @galambalazs: Even in a `mousemove` handler, I'm sure it's swamped by other factors. I completely agree it's more readable, and again, can only assume there's a good reason it's so convoluted.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder - jQuery often uses unneccessarily convulted code. Some people treat it as a JS bible, which it is cleary not. It's a library full of problems.

Comment: @galambalazs: Oh, don't worry, I don't make that mistake. There is some really horrible code in there (I was shocked when I first looked, a couple of years back; it's improved *some* since then). But *sometimes* there's a reason for what it does. Since the OP says yours doesn't work, but theirs does, I'm thinking there *may* be a reason in this case. Could well be that there isn't, of course.

Comment: It's because he runs the feature test before document is ready, which is needed to test scroll values (incr. fails, doc.body is selected, but it's `null` because doc is not ready).